# How can I force a listbox to a certain height? (height is automatically adjusted so the bottom row is not partially visible)

Tags: listbox, c++-cli, resize

I am resizing and positioning a listbox like this:

```
Rectangle r (x, y, width, height);
listbox->Bounds = r;
```

The height seems to be automatically adjusted to become a multiple of the height of an item.  (Making these numbers up): If the height of each row is 10, and I set the listbox height to 105, it is automatically adjusted to become 100.  This happens even when the listbox is not populated.  The result is a minor cosmetic problem occurring when the user re-sizes the window (and the listbox is re-sized along with it).

Is there a way to force the height?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the IntegralHeight property to False allows the partial display of items. The `ListBox` height can then be adjusted arbitrarily.